# sort select box options by inline css attributes (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have the following select box and want to sort it by `display:none` inlne attribute , that all the options which donot have `display:none` attribute will show at top and and rest of options will be showed after them . How to do this in jquery ?

**Code**

```
<select id="changeme"> 

<option style="display:none;">1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option style="display:none;">4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option style="display:none;">6</option> 
<option>7</option> 
<option style="display:none;">8</option>


</select>
```

i know that the options that have attribute `display:none` will not show but i want that my rendered html will look like this

```
<select id="changeme"> 


<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>5</option>  
<option>7</option> 
 <option style="display:none;">4</option>
 <option style="display:none;">6</option>
 <option style="display:none;">1</option>
 <option style="display:none;">8</option>


 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly instead of using style `display:none` I used `class=showLast` which might be easy

```
<select id="changeme">
    <option class="showLast">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option class="showLast">4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option class="showLast">6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option class="showLast">8</option>
</select>
```

​​​​​​​​
You can as well change the condition `this.className === showLast` depending on if you want options with class to be shown first or last.

```
var withClass = $('#changeme > option').map(function() {
    if (this.className === 'showLast') {
        return this;
    };
}).toArray();
$('#changeme').append(withClass);
```

​
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/5eHWH/2/)**

Hope this helps

Comment: is there any css solution for the same?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal not that i know of

Answer (score 0):

May not be the good solution, but it works

```
var options = [];
var select = $('#changeme');
select.find('option').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.css('display') === 'none'){
        options.push($this.wrap('<p />').parent().html());
    }
    else{
        options.unshift($this.wrap('<p />').parent().html());
    } 
})  
select.html(options.join(''));
```

**EDIT:**

This is a simpler code (but may lead to hidden options as `select` value)

```
$('#changeme').find('option').filter(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.css('display') == 'none')
        $this.appendTo($this.parent());
})
```